# Have xib's size conform to contents?

Tags: swift, xcode, xib, nib

I'm creating a xib for a custom view of mine. I want the main part of the view to be 44 pixels high, with a 4 pixel shadow below it, and have the width fit the contents of the view. Right now, I have my xib's `Size` set to `Freeform`.

But my problem now is that my xib is 500x500 pixels, while my view is meant to only stretch to the width of its contents and its height should only be 44 pixels.

How can I make it so that the xib's size changes according to the views inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Freeform views won't automatically resize in the interface builder from the autolayout constraints of its content; they do at runtime if you set your constraints right.

If the size of your view in the IB mismatches your constraints' description, you'll get a *conflicting constraints* warning that won't affect the way the view is displayed during runtime. You can remove them by manually resizing the frame in the IB so all constraints are satisfied.